# C++ - Avoiding memory leak with exceptions

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, exception

Let's say you have some code like this:

```
void myFunction()
{
    myClass * mine = new myClass();
    // body of function
    delete mine;
}
```

If an exception is thrown within the body of the function, the `delete` will never be called and a memory leak will result. What is the best way to alleviate this, other than using any of the managed pointers within `<memory>`.

Comment: Write your own managed pointer class?  (Note: don't.  Use an existing implementation.)

Comment: Create your own class that manages the pointer.

Comment: What is your aversion to using a tried and tested managed pointer?

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` (C++11) is the way to go.

Comment: Thats why you should deallocate memory in the destructor

Comment: @user2365568 Except the pointer goes out of scope at the end of `myFunction()`. How would you deallocate it in the destructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to manage it without smart pointer is available, though not recommended:

```
void myFunction()
{
    myClass * mine = 0;
    try {
        mine = new myClass();
        // body of function
    }
    catch(...) {
        delete mine;
        throw;
    }
    delete mine;
}
```

Again this method is more error prone (code duplicate etc), RAII is preferred as answered before .

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer if the STL is not available (i.e. on some microcontrollers)

Answer (score 12):

Use RAII. There are many ways to do this, the best would be to use tried and tested solutions such as smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<myClass>` or `boost::scoped_ptr<myClass>`.

If you want to go through the exercise of implementing a RAII solution yourself, it could be in the form of a scope guard:

```
struct guard
{
  myClass* ptr;
  guard(myClass* p) : ptr(p) {}
  ~guard() { delete ptr; }
  guard(const guard&) = delete;
  guard& operator=(const guard&) = delete;
};
```

Note that RAII requires that the code be in a try block at some level.

Comment: Is using smart pointers the only solution to this? There is no way using raw pointers?

Comment: @user2612743 I just gave you another solution. A scope guard.

Answer (score 2):

Memory Leaks of such kind can easily be avoided by using `std::auto_ptr` or (with C++11) `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

void myFunction()
{
    std::unique_ptr<myClass> mine(new myClass());
    // Use mine as before, mine->foo() or *mine is totally valid
    // The instance of myClass is deleted as soon as the unique_ptr goes out of scope
    // body of function
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there anyway to do it without using managed pointers?

Comment: Define your own class like juanchopanza said. But that is error prone, and it would basically be a case of 'reinventing the wheel'. `std::unique_ptr` is a very lightweight encapsulation. When you speak about managed pointers you almost always mean `std::shared_ptr` which introduces the overhead of reference counting etc.

Comment: `is there anyway to do it without using managed pointers`  Even with home-made code, you're "managing the pointer".

Answer (score 1):

Your first preference should be not to use `new` at all. There's nothing in your stripped down example that suggests stack allocation would fail:

```
void myFunction()
{
    myClass mine;
    // body of function
}
```

If you do need to allocate on the heap, then prefer to use RAII wrappers (preferring ones in the standard library over custom ones), or try/catch structures.